# Tomcat6 .war file deployment issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat6, war

I am very new, so please excuse the naive question.

I was asked to fix an implementation of a webapp on a tomcat6 server that someone else had designed. I saved a copy of the .war file locally, and in the process of messing with the deployed application broke it.

So I undeployed that webapp, and tried to re-deploy it using my backup .war file. But instead of a working app, I got a bunch of errors. (attached)

Is there anything else I need to do to properly deploy a webapp using Tomcat Web Application Manager besides select the .war file and click deploy? And if not, what are the typical things that go wrong in this scenario?

Here are the errors I get:

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:453)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

note: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

Comment: A recommendation, move your project to Apache POM to solve dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below error message it looks like you are missing the library jar for fileupload API.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException

Please check the tomcat/webapps//WEB-INF/lib for the commons-fileupload.jar file.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Jar file missing either in tomcat/lib path or tomcat/webapps//WEB-INF/lib

Thnx,
Subhash